# Linq orderby calculation

Tags: c#, sql, linq, sorting

I have an SQL query that I built for a tool a while ago and I'm remaking the tool in MVC and using LINQ to Entities.

I can't seem to figure out how to sort my list of Brands by weighting my Cars by man hours and their testing value.

Here's the SQL query I had in the old tool:

```
    SELECT Brand.ID, SUM(Car.EstManHours) - SUM(Car.EstManHours) * CAST(AVG(1.00 * TestingStatus.Value) AS DECIMAL(9 , 2)) / 100 AS Weighting
FROM TestingStatus INNER JOIN Car ON TestingStatus.ID = Car.StatusID
    INNER JOIN Team ON Car.TeamID = Team.TeamID 
    RIGHT OUTER JOIN Brand 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN SubCategory ON Brand.ID = SubCategory.BrandID ON Car.SubCategoryID = SubCategory.ID 
WHERE (Car.IsPunted == 'False')
GROUP BY Brand.YearID, Brand.FeatID
HAVING (Brand.YearID = @BrandYearID)
ORDER BY Weighting DESC
```

I've tried this, but whether I put descending or ascending the order doesn't actually change in the list, it keeps the sorting by Id:

```
var brands = (from b in _context.Brands
            join s in _context.SubCategorys on f.Id equals s.BrandId
            join c in _context.Cars on s.Id equals c.SubCategoryId
            where (f.YearId == yearId && c.IsPunted == false)
            orderby (c.ManHoursEst - (c.ManHoursEst * c.TestingStatu.Value / 100)) descending 
            select b).Distinct().ToList();
```

Would appreciate help on this conversion!

Thanks.

EDIT:

I'm now trying to get the order by and group by to work correctly.
The following query is listing tons of duplicates and not ordering properly as I don't think my weighting is done correctly.

```
var brands = (from b in _context.Brands
            join s in _context.SubCategorys on f.Id equals s.BrandId
            join c in _context.Cars on s.Id equals c.SubCategoryId
            where (f.YearId == yearId && c.IsPunted == false)
            let weighting = c.ManHoursEst - (c.ManHoursEst * c.TestingStatu.Value / 100)
            orderby weighting descending 
            group b by b.Id).SelectMany(x=>x).ToList();
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Your original query is performing a grouping - your LINQ query isn't.

Comment: @LanFeusT : For readability, I would use a 'let' clause where you compute your weighting, then ordering by 'weighting'. It wouldn't change the performance, or the output, it's just that an order by clause with a formula hurts my eyes :-P

Comment: @Tipx definitely a good idea! ^^ Thanks will do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Distinct` does not preserve sorting. That is your problem.

You could do a `group by` like in your SQL to mimic the `Distinct` and perform everything server side.

Comment: In fact, doing the group by wouldn't "Mimic the distinct", it would be the proper translation of his query so his distinct would stop mimicing his group by! ;-)

Comment: Is there a way I can convert that grouping back to a List<Brand>? Since doing the `group b by  c.ManHoursEst - (c.ManHoursEst*c.TestingStatu.Value/100)` converts it to a List<IGrouping<decimal, Brand>> ?

Comment: @LanFeusT: When you get your query right, you can just say `SelectMany(g => g).ToList()`. But your query is clearly wrong. Why are you grouping by that?

Comment: Ok so I'm trying to group by my Brand.Id and order by weighting. But clearly I'm doing something wrong there xD 

`var brands = (from b in _context.Brands
            join s in _context.SubCategorys on b.Id equals s.BrandId
            join c in _context.Cars on s.Id equals c.SubCategoryId
            where (b.YearId == yearId && c.IsPunted == false)
   let weighting = c.ManHoursEst - (c.ManHoursEst*c.TestingStatu.Value/100)
   orderby weighting descending
   group b by b.MilestoneId).SelectMany(g=>g).ToList();`

this gives me a list with lots of duplicates and not properly ordered.

Comment: I'm gonna mark this answer as correct as that was definitely my issue. I wasn't able to get the query right instead I just used my SQL query and dumped it in a stored procedure, which made it all much easier. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @LanFeusT: You know, your SQL query is not that hard to translate LINQ. I'm super duper busy at work though until after October 1. If you don't figure it out by then, come back to this post and leave me a comment which will remind me to come back to this post after October 6 (much needed vacation!) to edit in how to do it.